# Unable to bind to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: networking

I'm having difficulty with a system that was working yesterday. I haven't changed much - if anything since then. However, now whenever I try to start something that uses 127.0.0.1 as its ip address I get errors. For instance:

```
user@server:~# tcpserver 127.0.0.1 8080 echo
tcpserver: fatal: unable to bind: address not available
```

And a java app (the thing I'm really trying to start) throws this error:

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at 
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
```

the same tcpserver call works if I use 0.0.0.0 or the ip address assigned to eth0, but not when specifying 127.0.0.1.

I've been digging through all the logs and I don't see anything that jumps out at me. The `ifconfig -a` output is below in case that is useful. I've tried `ifdown lo; ifup lo` and even `ifup lo --force` - none of that seems to make any difference though. I've also rebooted the server a few times with no luck. I also tried `rm -rf /var/run/network/*` followed by another reboot (per https://serverfault.com/a/672217/262491), but no luck there either. `netstat -ano` shows nothing listening on port 8080 and nothing listening on 127.0.0.1.

```
user@server:~# ifconfig -a
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <redacted>
      inet addr:10.252.2.169  Bcast:10.252.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: <redacted>/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
      RX packets:18970 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:17158 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:4514198 (4.5 MB)  TX bytes:4194402 (4.1 MB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      LOOPBACK  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Source interfaces
# Please check /etc/network/interfaces.d before changing this file
# as interfaces may have been defined in /etc/network/interfaces.d
# NOTE: the primary ethernet device is defined in
# /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0
# See LP: #1262951
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg
```

I compared the ifconfig above to a working system and it looks like the root cause of this error may be that the loopback adapter doesn't seem to have 127.0.0.1 assigned. So the question becomes - How is this possible? and How do I fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `cat /etc/hosts` and also: `cat /etc/hostname.` We notice that your `lo` interface doesn't have the expected IP address.

Comment: `etc/hosts` (mostly one line for 127.0.0.1 + ipv6 stuff) and `/etc/hostname` 
 (one line with a hostname in it) were indeed one of the first things I checked. I ruled them out as sources of the problem early.

Answer (score 1):

This is rumored to be a known issue with the AWS AMI of ubuntu 14.04 (~May 2017). The fix is to restart until you get lucky or manually assign the IP address via something like: `ifup lo; ip addr add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo` when it happens.